# Matplotlib - Hide error bars' label & points in legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, enthought

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]
ydata = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
yerr_dat = 0.5

plt.figure()

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'go--', label='Data', zorder=1)

plt.errorbar(xdata, ydata, yerr = yerr_dat, zorder=2, fmt='ko')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

which will plot this:

[image]

I don't want the error points and the *None* label in the legend, how can I take those out?

I'm using *Canopy* in its version 1.0.1.1190.

---

### Edit

After trying Joe's solution with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]
ydata = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
yerr_dat = 0.5
value = 20

plt.figure()

scatt = plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'go--', label='Data', zorder=1)
hline = plt.hlines(y=5, xmin=0, xmax=40)
vline = plt.vlines(x=20, ymin=0, ymax=15)

plt.errorbar(xdata, ydata, yerr = yerr_dat, zorder=2, fmt='ko')

plt.legend([scatt, vline, hline], ['Data', 'Horiz line', 'Verti line = %d' % value], fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

I get this warning:

```
/home/gabriel/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/legend.py:628: UserWarning: Legend does not support [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0xa09a28c>]
Use proxy artist instead.

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist

  (str(orig_handle),))
```

and this output:

[image: plot2]

where the first label is not showing for some reason. Ideas?

---

### Edit 2

Turns out I was missing a comma in the line:

```
scatt, = plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'go--', label='Data', zorder=1)
```

After adding it everything worked like a charm. Thanks Joe!

Comment: For what it's worth, I cannot replicate this with Python 2.7.5, matplotlib 1.2.1 and IPython 0.13. Try to update your matplotlib.

Comment: @nordev - Matplotlib's legend behavior was changed in `1.1` or `1.2` (I can't remember which offhand).  Prior to this, all plotted artists would be shown in the legend, regardless of whether or not a `label` was explicitly assigned.  At any rate, updating mpl would fix it, but it's a design decision that was changed recently, rather than a bug.

Comment: @JoeKington Ah, I'm impressed by your never ending wisdom! I haven't used matplotlib pre 1.1 (I believe), so I suspected that this feature was introduced in one of the more recent versions, as I have never encountered this problem before.

Comment: According to `Canopy`'s own site (https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/) it uses `matplotlib` v 1.2.0, so this probably has been fixed starting from 1.2.1.

Comment: @nordev - I just know more weird quirks of matplotlib than I should. I should probably start spending less time making my figures pretty and more time making more of them... Ah well...

Comment: @Gabriel - Huh... I thought it was changed earlier than that. At any rate, it looks like that's when it was changed.  I'm suprised it was slipped in in a point release. Must have been considered a bug, but it was definitely present in earlier versions (though it would have displayed "Errorbar 1" instead of "None"). There was a refactor of the `Legend` class awhile back. Probably related to that.

Comment: @JoeKington I'm sorry to bother you again but I'm getting a weird warning when I apply tour solution. I'll update the answer, would you mind having a look at it?

Comment: @Gabriel - You're missing a comma. It should be `scat, = plt.plot...`. `plot` always returns a tuple, even when there's only one artist. (Which is dute to `plot`'s overloaded functionality to make it behave like matlab's `plot`.) It's a common "gotcha".

Comment: I had just noticed it! That's a sneaky comma :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On newer versions of matplotlib, what you're wanting is the default behavior. Only artists with an explicitly assigned label will appear in the legend.

However, it's easy to control what's displayed in the legend. Just pass in only the artists you'd like to label:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]
ydata = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
yerr_dat = 0.5

plt.figure()

dens = plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'go--', zorder=1)

plt.errorbar(xdata, ydata, yerr = yerr_dat, zorder=2, fmt='ko')

plt.legend(dens, ['Density Profile'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternately, you could specify `label='_nolegend_'` for the `errorbar` plot, but I don't know what versions of matplotlib support that, and passing in explicit lists of artists and labels will work for any version.

If you'd like to add other artists:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]
ydata = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
yerr_dat = 0.5

plt.figure()

# Note the comma! We're unpacking the tuple that `plot` returns...
dens, = plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'go--', zorder=1)
hline = plt.axhline(5)

plt.errorbar(xdata, ydata, yerr = yerr_dat, zorder=2, fmt='ko')

plt.legend([dens, hline], ['Density Profile', 'Ceiling'], loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: And what would I do if I have more than one legend to be displayed? Say that I'm also plotting an `hline` and I want a legend for it too? Sorry for extending the question.

Comment: Just add it to the list of artists that you're passing in. As my example is written, `dens` is actually a tuple with a single `Line2D` artist (`plot` always returns a tuple).  `legend` expects a sequence of artists and a sequence of labels.  I'll update my example in a second to show this.

Comment: I'm getting a warning when I try this: `UserWarning: Legend does not support [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0xa09a28c>]
Use proxy artist instead.` I'll update the question with the exact code that issues this warning.

Comment: Oops I just noticed that sneaky comma!